# New appcompatv7:27.0.1 dilaog builder buttons scroll issue

Tags: android

> appcompat library v7:27.0.1

when there is message which is scroll-able the buttons in dialog builder also becomes scroll-able when there are 3 buttons used

example as below

```
public void mesg(){

        final Context c = this;

        final AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(c)
                .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                //.setCancelable(false) // Cant Be Cancel By Pressing Back Key Only By Pressing Positive Button
                .setTitle("Test title")  // Can Also Be Done By HTML Style
                .setMessage("test message test message test messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest messagetest message")
                .setPositiveButton("Save All", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Select All", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    }
                })
                .setNeutralButton("Unselect All", null)
                .create();
        d.show();


    }
```

Images

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtDb5.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAxos.png)

[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1rze.png)

these issues were not there when i used v7:24.0.x ,i updated the SDK and build tools today only

Comment: I don't think this really an issue. If you have an `AlertDialog` with enough long message that buttons are almost out of screen, you need to have scroll for buttons section for clicking on them. I think this should be a correct behavior, because this can easily happen on ldpi screens.

Comment: hi when i use v7:24.0.3 support library the issue does not comes up only with this one